# select popup variant by enter instead of mouse click

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I am pressing ctrl + space vscode shows me variants (first image). Then I am pressing enter and vscode move my code below (second image) instead of selecting a popup variant.

[image]

[image]

I am pressing enter and variant should be selected.

Comment: Sounds super related: [vscode: pasting autocomplete with return key sometimes doesn't work](/q/75459891)

Comment: Related GitHub issues: [Suggestions box's first choice is sometimes selected, sometimes NOT #173387](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173387). And these closed as a dupe of the previous one: [Pressing enter to apply does not apply completion #173343](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173343) and [Issue when pressing enter key to apply suggestion. #173903](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173903). Does that first one cover your issue?

Comment: @user, the problem was in currently installed vue plugin. After restart vscode it works. Thanks!